# How to override HandleUnauthorizedRequest in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I'm migrating my project to asp.net core and I'm stuck in migrating my CustomAuthorization attribute for my controllers. Here is my code.

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url + "?returnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
        }
        else if (!Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "AcessDenied"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

then i used it to my controllers

```
[CustomAuthorization(Url = "/Admin/Account/Login", Roles = "Admin")]
public abstract class AdminController : Controller { }
```

so, basically i can use it to redirect to different login page when roles is not met. I have few areas and each of them have different login page. I tried using the **CookieAuthenticationOptions** like this

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Admin";
    options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Account/Login";
});
```

then on my admin controller

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Admin", Roles = "Admin")]
```

but after i login, it still cant get in.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code? Does it get executed? Where does it fail?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something similar in one of my projects.  This answer is NOT using AuthorizeAttribute; but it might help some one landing here from a google search.
In my case I am using it to authorize based on custom logic.

First my custom attribute class:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IMyDepedency _dp;
    public CustomAuthorizationAttribute(IMyDepedency dp)
    {
        _dp = dp;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var isValid = false;
       //write my validation and authorization logic here 
        if(!isValid)
        {
            var unauthResult = new UnauthorizedResult();

            context.Result = unauthResult;                
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I decorate my controllers like this:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof (CustomAuthorizationAttribute))]
```

Then in my Startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // Add framework services.
     services.AddMvc();

   // my other stuff that is not relevant in this post

     // Security
     services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizationAttribute>();
 }
```