# Redirecting on Authorize

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I've prepared the authentication like this in my *Start.cs*.

```
...
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(a => a.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidIssuer = "beep",
    ValidAudience = "bopp",
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecurityKeyOfProperLength"))
  });
...
```

When I decorate one of the methods in my controller using *[Authorize]* attribute, I no longer get the view it points to rendered. Instead, just as expected, I get 401 Unauthorized.

The next step I want to do is to be redirected to my login page, which is located in the controller *Security* and method *Login*. I don't know how to achieve it properly with no Q&D.

What I've tried to do is to google, of course, and I've found out a lot of examples on how to handle that from SPA. In my case it's good, old, plain MVC rendered on the backend so that's not applicable, as far I understand.

I've also seen that I can override *OnChallenge* but it wasn't recommended.

A bunch of links referred to 3rd parties like IDS and such. In my case, I want to learn the process and control it by micromanagement, at least for now. Mostly, because I want to learn that in depth.

How do I configure my *AddAuthentication* so that it bounces the user to the right controller and method (still using best practices)? A few hints on terms to look for would by great - I'm not lazy, just careful and uncertain of what's good stuff and what's other confused bloggers' production.

Comment: you can override HandleUnauthorizedRequestand redirect then you have to mark the controller actions to use

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV OK, so I've been googling it some more, based on your [suggestion about *HandleUnauthorizedRequestand*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) but I can't seem to override that method, it doesn't seem to exist. I googled [how to override it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446028/how-to-override-handleunauthorizedrequest-in-asp-net-core) but the answer to that didn't even use said method. I'm back at status *immensely uncertain*. Please advise...

Comment: just have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928277/redirect-to-another-page-when-user-is-not-authorized-in-asp-net-mvc3